# What is wrong with my definite integral?

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, solution-verification

This is the original equation it is asking for the area in between those two points.$$\int_\sqrt{2}^2{\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}}$$
I automatically took the integral and replaced with the identity for the inverse of **sec** and then plugged in the values. My question is if this is correct. $$sec^{-1}(2) \; -sec^{-1}(\sqrt{2})$$
Forgot to add but, if I were to simply this down more what would i do? I'm honestly not the best with the unit circle.

Comment: Looks good. You are probably expected to simplify.

Comment: It is correct. If you wanna see that for yourself then just make a substitution with x = sec(theta) and sure enough you'll get the same answer.

Comment: We have $\sec^{-1} (2)=\pi/3$ and for the other it is $\pi/4$,  For the standard angle with cosine $1/2$ is $\pi/3$ and the one with cosine $1/\sqrt{2}$ is $\pi/4$.

Comment: @ André Ok so how is it that you got that? Ok so when we go back to cosine from inverse secant we flip the value?

Comment: If my secant is $2$ then my cosine is $1/2$. At one time you knew that the $60$ degree angle has cosine $1/2$.

Comment: Oh ok I understand, I do not remember that though, Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. It is useful to remember the trigonometric functions, or at least sine and cosine, for the angles $0,\pi/6,\pi/4,\pi/3,\pi/2$. For other related ones less than $0$ or bigger than $\pi/2$,s. sketch the sine and cosine curves.  The answer to your area problem is $\pi/12$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas do you think you can assist me with another question similar to this really quick?

Comment: @CarlosV You can get help in the comments if you need it (I am more than willing to help), but (depending on the question) making a new post might be better

Comment: I will post a new question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse trig function is trig function of its reciprocal value. You can draw a right angled triangle with leg, hypotenuse as $ x,1 $ respectively to simply verify this.

$${\sec^{-1}2-\sec^{-1}\sqrt 2}={\cos^{-1}\frac12-\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}= 60^0- 45^0 = 15^0. $$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, since, $0<\sec^{-1}(2)< \frac{\pi}{2}$ & $0<\sec^{-1}(\sqrt 2)< \frac{\pi}{2}$

hence, it can more simplified  as follows by using following formula $$\cos (A-B)=\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B$$ $$\cos^2A+\sin^2A=1$$
Now, we have 
$$\color{blue}{\sec^{-1}(2)-\sec^{-1}(\sqrt 2)}$$
$$=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)$$
$$=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\right)$$
$$=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}\right)$$$$=\color{red}{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}\right)}$$

Comment: This seems really excessive... $\sec^{-1}(2) = \frac{\pi}{3}$, and $\sec^{-1}(\sqrt{2}) = \frac{\pi}{4}$... subtract the latter from the former and you get $\frac{\pi}{12}$. Easy as... pi XD

Comment: You are right but how to express $\frac{\pi}{12}$ in form of inverse of some trigonometric function

Comment: Do we really need to? We are simply subtracting one value from another, and both are extremely well known trig identities taught to first year trig students. I think it is far easier to just remember the identities than to go through all that work... I mean, who possibly remembers the value of $\cos^{-1}(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}})$??